# Trigger an action when email is received in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I´m planning to port a web application I did that parses some emails on my account to a windows phone app. Is it possible to know from my application when I receive an email and access the data it contains? Is there any event for that action?

Comment: How do you check it in your webapp? Periodically query your mail server? You'll have to do this here as well.  There is no general hook for a received email because this is handeled by the respective application.